# In CQRS, is it okay to call external services from Sagas/Process Manager?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

In my domain where I am applying CQRS, there are some external service calls in order to some validation. I am a bit puzzled about where to put these calls. I am considering to put these calls to my Process manager on the other hand AFAIK the process manager should be a simple state machine that reacts on events and dispatch commands to other aggregates. I can think of two solutions:

1-) One solution is to make these calls and depending on the service call, transition to another state by self publishing an event. Though I don't like the idea Process manager publishes events.

2-) I can wrap my service calls behind another interface and that service call itself can raise the event. Though I don't like this idea since an event should be persisted before publishing.

How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: Call the external service

Comment: Yes but from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: call the external services from the Saga but invert the dependency by using an `Interface`

Unlike Aggregates, which must be pure (no dependency to anything that touches the infrastructure, nor abstract neither concrete), Sagas are domain models that may call external services. But because they are also from the Domain layer, they may not depend on the Infrastructure. You manage to do that [inverting the dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), by defining an `Interface` in the Domain layer with an implementation in the Infrastructure. In this way, the Domain owns the interface and not the Infrastructure.

In other words, you must use an Anti-corruption layer when communicating with external models, and that is that `Interface` for.

Btw, in this way you increase the Saga's testability, for free.

> 1-) One solution is to make these calls and depending on the service call, transition to another state by self publishing an event. Though I don't like the idea Process manager publishes events.

Me neither, only Aggregates should generate domain events.

> 2-) I can wrap my service calls behind another interface and that service call itself can raise the event. Though I don't like this idea since an event should be persisted before publishing.

This feels weird.

Comment: Ok I agree with everything you say. But the last missing part. How do I evaluate the result of the service call then?.  I guess from that point on I directly issue the command ?

Comment: @user254540 I would maintain a `validationStatus` as private state in the Saga, with possible values: `not-started` (before the validation), `started`, `failed` (transport failures, for retries), `rejected` or `passed`. How many statuses it depends on how you run the Saga and how you should be able to restart it in case of system failure (server is restarted).

Comment: Though state change of the saga should happen over events. How will I change the state after the service call if I am not going to publish an event ?

Comment: @user254540 There are other modes to have state, not only with events. You can persist the state anywhere. For example, I persist it in a NoSQL database but any key/value store would also work.

Comment: You are probably right. Though I strictly event source my Sagas too. That is due to I use actors via akka.net and events are the idiomatic way for persistence.

Comment: @user254540 Event-sourced Sagas are a very nice thing, they are stateless (and we know what stateless gives us) but in this case they can't be because the external system is not also event-sourced.

Answer (score 1):

I think the process manager state machine is the way to go. You have 3 separate states:

1. You have unvalidated input.
2. You are waiting for an external process to validate the input.
3. You received the validation result.

To my mind, it fits the simple state machine perfectly.

In real world, of course, the last state is split into another 3:

- Validation result is positive.
- Validation result is negative.
- Validation result is undefined, the external service crashed.

This, and any retry logic, fits a simple state machine perfectly, too.

Comment: I understand but from where do you make the Service call itself? Right inside the Process Manager?

Comment: I'd call the service in the manager and self-publish the event. IDK how to best handle the state transition between "external service started" and "external service completed", because this event likely should not be persisted.

Comment: Actually that is a requirement for me. But it is solved. Since before tha call happens some event causes that service call.

Answer (score 0):

My Sagas are the same thing as an Aggregates. So when I have a complex business process requiring several steps, any of which might require requesting some 3rd party service or human action, this business process looks like the following:

[image]

Each logical step ends with publishing an event.

There are [couple](https://medium.com/@wrong.about/example-of-service-boundaries-identification-e9077c513560) of [examples](https://medium.com/@wrong.about/service-boundaries-identification-example-in-e-commerce-a2c01a1b8ee9) that demonstrate this technique in more detail, both of which are based on classical [Pat Helland' paper](http://adrianmarriott.net/logosroot/papers/LifeBeyondTxns.pdf).

Comment: I humbly disagree that Aggregates should do the service call. An aggregate is something that takes a command and publishes event with a new state.

Comment: As you wish :)⠀ ⠀